# java 3d face recognition program

Tags: java

I'm still a novice Java programmer. 
I have downloaded some projects on the internet but I have some issue running one of the project. 
That project is about face recognition. 
It can successfully be compiled but when I want to load an image, the file pictures don't show in the JFileChooser.

I think the problem is at this part:

```
    File folder = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //System.out.println("1 "+folder);
            FileFilter dirFilter = new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.exists() && pathname.isDirectory();
                }
            };
            FileFilter jpgFilter = new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    String filename = pathname.getName();
                    boolean jpgFile = (filename.toUpperCase().endsWith("JPG")
                            || filename.toUpperCase().endsWith("JPEG"));
                    return pathname.exists() && pathname.isFile() && jpgFile;
                }
            };

            File[] folders = folder.listFiles(dirFilter);
            //System.out.println("2 "+folders);
            trainingSet.clear();
            faceBrowser.empty();

            for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {              //For each folder in the training set directory
                File[] files = folders[i].listFiles(jpgFilter);
                System.out.println("3   " + files);
                for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                    trainingSet.add(files[j]);
                }
            }

            File[] files = trainingSet.toArray(new File[1]);

            jlist.setListData(files);
            //there is no image files in the folderwai
            //System.out.println(files);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println(files[0]);
                Face f = new Face(files[i]);
                f.description = "Face image in database.";
                f.classification = files[i].getParentFile().getName();
                faceBrowser.addFace(f);
                faces.add(f);
            }

            jlStatus.setIndeterminate(false);
            jlStatus.setString(files.length + " files loaded from " + folders.length + " folders.");
            jlStatus.paintImmediately(jlStatus.getVisibleRect());


            jspFaceBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            main.invalidate();

            jbTrain.setEnabled(true);
            jbCropImage.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: What is `trainingSet` declared as?

Answer (score 1):

This only supports files that end with the extensions `.jpg` or `.jpeg`. If the file you are loading ends with a `.png` or some other extension, you'll have to convert it to `.jpg` using a converter, probably an online one like [png2jpg.com](http://png2jpg.com/). Once you've converted it, it should show up in the `JFileChooser`.

This behavior is declared on this line:

```
boolean jpgFile = (filename.toUpperCase().endsWith("JPG") || filename.toUpperCase().endsWith("JPEG"));
```

You could change `"JPG"` to something else, but, just to be sure, I'd leave it alone until you become a little more at-home with messing around in programming.